# App cannot connect to mongodb on Heroku unless sever is running on local machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

The problem is that app only connects to mongodb on heroku when im also running connected to the server on my local machine (npm run server.js)

server.js

```
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
console.log(uri);
mongoose.connect(uri,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log('Unable to connect to database');
            process.exit(1);
        }
        else
            console.log('Successfully connected to the database')
    });


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App is running`);
});
```

If the above code is not running on my local machine the app wont connect to database on heruko.

`process.env.MONGODB_URI` is in a .env file and I have also get the config var on heroku with the same value and key.

```
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon server --ignore client /",
    "dev": "concurrently \" npm run client\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

These are the scripts in my package.json

Comment: Hello, where is located the .env file on your local machine?

Comment: Also, is  `console.log(uri)` printing the mongodb path that you have in your local .env file?

Comment: @andresmunozit .env is located in the same location as my sever.js file. And yes, console.log(uri) prints the mongodb path